# Shapley Kernel Proof

Tags: game-theory, machine-learning

I read the paper about [SHAP](https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/hash/8a20a8621978632d76c43dfd28b67767-Abstract.html).

I think this paper is very interesting ! I would like to understand the algorithm, but I cannot follow the below fact.

\begin{equation}
X^T WX=\dfrac{1}{M-1}I+cJ
\end{equation}

where $W$ is a diagonal matrix with Shapley kernel weights for each arrow of $X$, $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the matrix of all ones.

And I cannot follow the below fact.
\begin{equation}
(X^T WX)^{-1}=I+\dfrac{1}{M-1}(I-J) \ \ (c\rightarrow \infty)
\end{equation}

Could you mind telling me how to prove this fact.

Comment: The reference you give is only a short abstract ! We need more to understand what all this is about...

Comment: Besides, have you attempted to multiply the 2 RHS (Right Hand Sides matrices) : they are supposed to give identity matrix $I$, isn't it ?

Comment: please click supplemental in URL of SHAP !

Comment: what are Right Hand Sides matrices ??

Comment: Plainly multiply the RHS of your identities : $\dfrac{1}{M-1}I+cJ$ by $I+\dfrac{1}{M-1}(I-J)$ should give $I$.

Comment: I have clicked button "Supplemental" but I am unable to open the loaded (compressed) files.

Comment: please access the below url.

Comment: [shapley kernel proof](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Scott-Lundberg/publication/321288820_shapley_kernel_proof/data/5a18ebea4585155c26a95db3/shapley-kernel-proof.pdf?origin=publication_list)

Comment: If we use [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), \begin{equation}
(X^T WX)^{-1}=(M-1)I-\dfrac{M-1}{M}J \ \ (c\rightarrow \infty)
\end{equation} It is not equal to the fact... I cannot understand...

Answer (score 1):

I think there is typographical error in the NIPS supplemental paper.

\begin{equation}
X^TWX = \dfrac{1}{M-1}I+cJ \ \ (\mathrm{NIPS})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
X^TWX = \dfrac{M-1}{M}I+cJ \ \ (\mathrm{Update})
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

If we suppose equation (1), using sherman-morrison formula, we can get  equation (2).

\begin{eqnarray}
(X^T WX)^{-1}&=&\dfrac{M}{M-1}I-\dfrac{\dfrac{M}{M-1}\dfrac{M}{M-1}cJ}{1+\dfrac{M}{M-1}cM}\\
&\rightarrow&\dfrac{M}{M-1}I-\dfrac{1}{M-1}J \ \ (c\rightarrow \infty)\\
&=&I+\dfrac{1}{M-1}(I-J) \ \ (c\rightarrow \infty)
\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: If it is true, I can understand that equation (1) represent $X^T WX$.